# Python slicing, moving old slicing places?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

i previously got:

```
self.memory = np.zeros((MEMORY_CAPACITY, s_dim * 2 + a_dim + 1), dtype=np.float32)
```

but i needed to add a variable "done" to this memory, so i did:

```
self.memory = np.zeros((MEMORY_CAPACITY, s_dim * 2 + a_dim + 2), dtype=np.float32)
```

and now i added the variable "done" in the memory with:

```
def store_transition(self, s, a, r, s_, done):
    transition = np.hstack((s, a, [r], s_, done))
    index = self.pointer % MEMORY_CAPACITY  # replace the old memory with new memory
    self.memory[index, :] = transition
```

so now it's added, but i also need to get it back in my other function:

```
    indices = np.random.choice(MEMORY_CAPACITY, size=BATCH_SIZE)
    bt = self.memory[indices, :]
    bs = bt[:, :self.s_dim]
    ba = bt[:, self.s_dim: self.s_dim + self.a_dim]
    br = bt[:, -self.s_dim - 1: -self.s_dim]
    bs_ = bt[:, -self.s_dim:]
    bd = bt[:, here should be done]
```

so bd should contain the done variable, i am personally thinking about that that should be:

```
 bd = bt[:, -1:]
```

but i am not sure about that....

furthermore some old placement has to change right, because the array became bigger, but i have no idea which, what and how....

anyone that could help me out?

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean about the part *furthermore some old ...*

But the numpy slicing syntax works. See this example:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(5, 6)
>>> x.shape
(5, 6)
>>> x
array([[-0.66028509, -0.03515113,  0.54097151,  1.64021491,  1.55407344,
        -1.88961789],
       [-0.73310028, -0.38558638,  0.33200719, -0.142615  ,  0.57087033,
        -0.67726621],
       [ 0.32542737, -1.13508259,  1.58907859,  0.94438687,  0.33949198,
         1.52579515],
       [ 0.59211854,  0.39976888,  0.13617402,  0.57993582, -0.25274804,
        -1.15533191],
       [ 0.21203948,  0.72443024, -1.74406077,  0.97494208,  0.12653774,
        -0.00668887]])
>>> x[:, :-1]
array([[-0.66028509, -0.03515113,  0.54097151,  1.64021491,  1.55407344],
       [-0.73310028, -0.38558638,  0.33200719, -0.142615  ,  0.57087033],
       [ 0.32542737, -1.13508259,  1.58907859,  0.94438687,  0.33949198],
       [ 0.59211854,  0.39976888,  0.13617402,  0.57993582, -0.25274804],
       [ 0.21203948,  0.72443024, -1.74406077,  0.97494208,  0.12653774]])
>>> x[:, :-1].shape
(5, 5)
>>> x[:, -1:]
array([[-1.88961789],
       [-0.67726621],
       [ 1.52579515],
       [-1.15533191],
       [-0.00668887]])
>>> x[:, -1:].shape
(5, 1)
```